# Why is the counter not increasing in this binary search code in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, counter, binary-search

```
def binary_search(array,key,left,right):
    if left>right:
        return -1
    mid=(right+left)//2

    if key==array[mid]:
        return mid
    i=0
    if key<array[mid]:
        i+=1
        print("subarray at step {} : {}".format(i,array[left:mid]))
        return binary_search(array,key,left,mid-1)

    elif key>array[mid]:
        i+=1
        print("subarray at step {} : {}".format(i,array[mid:right]))
        return binary_search(array,key,mid+1,right)



array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,222,333]
res= binary_search(array,88,0,len(array))

print(res if res!=-1 else "Not found")
```

In this binary search code, I couldn't figure out why the counter wan not working. Each time the `i`
is printed a 1. The counter doesn't increase. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Because you set `i = 0` each time before incrementing it...

Comment: If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: You're calling the search function recursively. For each call, only a section of the full array is passed. `i` always starts as `0` for the section.

Comment: @wwii I tried using the debugger in pycharm a few times. But I couldn't figure out how. Do you have any blogs or youtube vidoes I could refer to learn debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i is being printed as 1 because you are i is being set to 0 inside binary_search function on each call. try moving out initiaization of i outside the function.

```
def binary_search(array,key,left,right):
    global i
    if left>right:
        return -1
    mid=(right+left)//2

    if key==array[mid]:
        return mid
    # i=0
    if key<array[mid]:
        i+=1
        print("subarray at step {} : {}".format(i,array[left:mid]))
        return binary_search(array,key,left,mid-1)

    elif key>array[mid]:
        i+=1
        print("subarray at step {} : {}".format(i,array[mid:right]))
        return binary_search(array,key,mid+1,right)


i =0
array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,222,333]
res= binary_search(array,88,0,len(array))
```

You need to change the scope of variable i to make it global.

Answer (score 0):

make **i** as global variable and to assing valuable  call **global** keywoard

```
i = 0
def binary_search(array,key,left,right):
    if left>right:
        return -1
    mid=(right+left)//2
    # i=0

    if key==array[mid]:
        return f'it found position {mid}'
    
    if key<array[mid]:
        global i 
        i = i+1
        print("subarray at step {} : {}".format(i,array[left:mid]))
        return binary_search(array,key,left,mid-1)

    elif key>array[mid]:
        i+=1
        print("subarray at step {} : {}".format(i,array[mid:right]))
        return binary_search(array,key,mid+1,right)



array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,222,333]
res= binary_search(array,88,0,len(array))
print(len(array))

print(res if res!=-1 else "Not found")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have to give global while declaring the variable? This code works. Like `global i 
i=0`

Comment: no you dont check the third `if`  I call there the global  keywoard  `global i ` otherwise you will get an error